# Pyplot legend: left alignment of a title

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I want my legend title to be to the left of labels. How can this be achieved?
Just to be clear, left alignment of title above the labels is not what I'm asking for. I want the title to be approximately on the same horizontal level as the middle label.
Instead of this:

[image]

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and give an example of how you would like the legend to look?

Answer (score 3):

One option to place the title to the left of the legend items is to take the title out of the vertical packer that makes up the legend and pack it horizontally with the legend columns.
It will then align to the top of the newly created very first column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(4):
    ax.plot(np.arange(4)+i, label="label {}".format(i+1))

legend = ax.legend(title="Looong Title", ncol=2, loc="upper left")

def legend_title_left(leg):
    c = leg.get_children()[0]
    title = c.get_children()[0]
    hpack = c.get_children()[1]
    c._children = [hpack]
    hpack._children = [title] + hpack.get_children()

legend_title_left(legend)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a better way to obtain it, but to have something similar to what you ask, you can try in this way:

```
leg = ax.legend(title='Title')
leg._legend_box.set_width(120)
leg.get_title().set_position((-50, -50))
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but there are too many problems with this solutions: some wasted space on the right and on the top, and I couldn't make it work with 2 columns.